# Store sudo password in encryped file

Tags: sudo, password, encryption

I want to store my sudo password in an encrypted file.

Only my user ID can access this file.

Furthermore only one program needs access to this file after it is created. Therefore even after creating this file even I don't need to read it, just the single program (bash script).

Before the usual warnings about entering password in a script that appears in log files, the password won't appear in the script anywhere. It will be typed into the sudo request password prompt.

Also `/etc/sudoers` method of adding my user ID will not work for the script.

Comment: I've only had limited experience with it, but how about `gpg`?  You can encrypt a file with it and provide more than one person as the receiver of the file.  I'm not sure if that satisfies your needs.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: You are aware that your password is already stored encrypted, right? There's no plain text password storage going on, it's salted and encrypted before storage. When you enter your password, it compares it against that and not against some plain text password. As such, and you having as many points as you do, I'm at a loss while trying to figure out what it is that you're asking.